# my app is not showing in the list to open shared location

Tags: android, intentfilter, deeplink

Hi i am developing an app to open shared location on google map fragment inside app .When user touches a location link shared my app should shown in open with list. here is my manifest

this is what i have tried by adding intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="maps.google.com" android:pathPattern="/maps"/>
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="maps.google.com" android:pathPattern="/maps"/>
  <data android:scheme="geo"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I expect that on click location my app will be shown in open with dialogue.

Comment: What is the current behaviour, can you specify that please?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with this Manifest Entry and it's working for me.

```
<activity
        <intent-filter>  
          <!-- Filter to run activity without geo --> 
            <action android:name="com.example.MYACTION" />                
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                     
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>   
            <!-- Filter for geo scheme geo -->                  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />               
            <data android:scheme="geo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

onCreate() of My Activity is like below

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  Intent intent = getIntent();  
  String action = intent.getAction();
  Uri data = intent.getData();

  if(Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) ) {
    if(data != null && "geo".equals(data.getScheme())) {  

      // Displaying map when there is geo Data
    }
  }
  else {
    // Other code when there is no geo DATA from intent
  }
}
```

You can Try and let me know.

Comment: @XeonTechnologies Glad to know this Helped. You can upvote and accept if it solved your problem.